# Isolated Storage to store recent lists, windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

`enter code here`I have got isolated storage working but it's only storing one item.

I want to be able to store a list of favourites for the user to use in a list.

At the moment, i can store loads of stops, but when i open the application again, it only rememers the last item. and deletes the rest.

```
private void ApplicationBarFavouriteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings  settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        // txtInput is a TextBox defined in XAML.
        if (!settings.Contains("userData"))
        {
            settings.Add("userData", busStopName.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            settings["userData"] = busStopName.Text;
        }
        settings.Save();
        MessageBox.Show("Bus Stop was added to your favourites");
    }
```

then for displaying the list

```
 if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("userData"))
        {
            listFav.Items.Add(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["userData"] as string); 

        }
```

EDIT:

```
 private void ApplicationBarFavouriteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {


       IsolatedStorageSettings  settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;


    List<string> favourites = settings["favourites"] as List<string>;

       if (favourites == null)
       {
           favourites = new List<string>();
           settings.Add("favourites", favourites);
       }

       favourites.Add(busStopName.Text);

       settings["favourites"] = favourites;
}
```

displaying the data

```
 if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("favourites"))
        {
            listFav.Items.Add(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["favourites"] as List<string>);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access your settings like you would a hash/dictionary.  So if your store information in `settings["bob"]`, you will overwrite `settings["bob"]` when you next store something with the same **key** ("bob").  In your case, you're using the key "userData", every time you use `settings["userData"] = "something";`, you're overwriting what is stored in that **key** in the settings.

You could use something like the following (I've renamed your setting to "favourites" so that it is more descriptive of it's contents):

```
List<string> favourites;

settings.TryGetValue("favourites", out favourites);

if (favourites == null)
{
    favourites = new List<string>();
    settings.Add("favourites", favourites);
}

favourites.Add(busStopName.Text);

settings["favourites"] = favourites;
```

and for displaying it:

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("userData"))
{
    listFav.Items.AddRange(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["favourites"] as List<string>);
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you.

I get the following message - KeyNotFoundException 

when it hits this line

`List<string> favourites = settings["favourites"] as List<string>;`

Comment: I've changed that line to use the TryGetValue() method instead.  This will attempt to get the value without causing an exception.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I thanks, i have added that. But i am now getting "systems.collections.generic.list`1[S...." can't see it all. also it's only keeping one of the saved it once. 

Not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to store a generic List of type string of Stops and then read this List from the ApplicationSettings, add a new stop to the List and then store the List back to the ApplicationSettings.